# Copy Formula or Fill down

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using vba to copy formula from multiple cells and paste to a large number of cells. Here's my code -

```
Sub FillFormulae()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As Worksheet: WS = Sheets("Main")
WS.Range("E15:P15").Copy
WS.Range("E16:P" & MainDataLastCell).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
WS.Range("S15:EA15").Copy
WS.Range("S16:EA" & MainDataLastCell).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

End Sub
```

MainDataLastCell is a global variable which has a value for 312896 for the current data. This can be more or less depending on the data.

The problem is this code is taking more than 4 hours to complete. Do you guys think if I use "Filldown" instead of copy formula it will take less time?

Comment: This code wont even run unless you use `Set WS = Sheets("Main")`

Comment: sorry I was checking if can select both.. honest rookie mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest that you try

1. turning off calculation
2. turning off screenupdating

The code below also fixes the compile error as `WS = Sheets("Main")` won't work

```
Const MainDataLastCell = 312896

Sub FillFormulae()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim lngCalc As Long

Set WS = Sheets("Main")

With Application
    lngCalc = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With WS
    .Range("E16:P" & MainDataLastCell).FormulaR1C1 = .Range("E15:P15").FormulaR1C1
    .Range("S16:EA" & MainDataLastCell).FormulaR1C1 = .Range("S15:EA16").FormulaR1C1
End With


With Application
    .Calculation = lngCalc
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @brettdj. I'll try this and let you know. The formulae I'm use are calculation intensive hence turning off calculation while updating will help.

Answer (score 1):

How about the below? With a simple formula this is only taking about a minute to run on my machine.

```
Sub fillformulae()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim icol As Integer
Dim irow As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet: WS = Sheets("Main")

For icol = 5 To 16
    WS.Range(Cells(16, icol), Cells(MainDataLastCell, icol)).Formula = WS.Cells(15, icol).Formula
Next

For icol = 19 To 131
    WS.Range(Cells(16, icol), Cells(MainDataLastCell, icol)).Formula = WS.Cells(15, icol).Formula
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thomas. Thanks for this approach. This gave me an idea to limit the number of columns I'm updating. As suggested by @brettdj, I'll try with turning off screen updating and calculation.